# Initial state definition for QAOA

Tags: programming, qaoa

There are a few options already discussed and suggested how to pass the initial state to the QAOA module.
I tried all but no one works in my case. Maybe, there are any other ideas?

So, I created the initial state as:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
circ.h(0)
circ.h(1)
circ.h(2)
circ.h(3)
backend=Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
job = execute(circ, backend)
result = job.result()
init_state = result.get_statevector(circ)
print(init_state)
```

then, by passing it to QAOA:

```
qaoa = QAOA(qubitOp, optimizer, p=3, initial_state=init_state,
                mixer=mixerop, initial_point=init_point,
                callback=store_intermediate_result, quantum_instance=qi)
```

I got the error:

````
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\algorithms\minimum_eigen_solvers\qaoa\var_form.py in construct_circuit(self, parameters, q)
     83         # initialize circuit, possibly based on given register/initial state
     84         if self._initial_state is not None:
---> 85             stateVector = CircuitStateFn(self._initial_state.construct_circuit('circuit'))
     86             circuit = stateVector.to_circuit_op()
     87         else:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'construct_circuit'

```
````

Comment: Hi, What are the things that you have tried? This will help people to understand the problem better and able to help. Also, take a look at this question https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15623/9858 Maybe it will be helpful. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly what are suggested in the answer to this question, but got the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from qiskit.aqua.components.initial_states import Custom
initial_state = Custom(num_qubits , state = 'zero') #if you want to start with zero state
```

note if you to specify an initial state in equal superposition, you just need to change `state = 'uniform'` .

And if you want a custom state_vector then you can specify it as:

```
initial_state = Custom(num_qubits , state_vector = [1,0,0,0,...] )
```

Note that the length of the vector is $2^n$ where $n$ is the number qubits.. so this might not be the most practical way to do thing.

---

Once you specify all of that, you can just specify it in your QAOA class parameters:

```
qaoa = QAOA(qubit_op,optimizer, initial_state = initial, quantum_instance=quantum_instance)
```

---

Below is a full working script from end to end: (I took the script from one of the Qiskit's tutorial and modified it to have an initial state like you wanted)

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

from qiskit import BasicAer
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit.optimization.applications.ising import graph_partition
from qiskit.optimization.applications.ising.common import random_graph, sample_most_likely

num_nodes = 4
w = random_graph(num_nodes, edge_prob=0.8, weight_range=10, seed=48)
print(w)


G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(w)
layout = nx.random_layout(G, seed=10)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']
nx.draw(G, layout, node_color=colors)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=layout, edge_labels=labels);


def brute_force():
    # use the brute-force way to generate the oracle
    def bitfield(n, L):
        result = np.binary_repr(n, L)
        return [int(digit) for digit in result]  # [2:] to chop off the "0b" part

    L = num_nodes
    max = 2**L
    minimal_v = np.inf
    for i in range(max):
        cur = bitfield(i, L)

        how_many_nonzero = np.count_nonzero(cur)
        if how_many_nonzero * 2 != L:  # not balanced
            continue

        cur_v = graph_partition.objective_value(np.array(cur), w)
        if cur_v < minimal_v:
            minimal_v = cur_v
    return minimal_v

sol = brute_force()
print(f'Objective value computed by the brute-force method is {sol}')

qubit_op, offset = graph_partition.get_operator(w)


from qiskit.aqua import aqua_globals
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance

aqua_globals.random_seed = 10598
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 10000)    
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter= 1,tol=0.000000001)  
initial =  Custom(4 , state = 'zero')
qaoa = QAOA(qubit_op,optimizer, initial_state = initial, quantum_instance=quantum_instance)

result = qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue()

x = sample_most_likely(result.eigenstate)
ising_sol = graph_partition.get_graph_solution(x)

print(ising_sol)
print(f'Objective value computed by QAOA is {graph_partition.objective_value(x, w)}')
```

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hope I was able to help. no problem. :)